# Countdown timer start/stop/reset button with Apps Script to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some issues about countdown timer with start/stop/reset command button on Google Sheets . how to write a script for it by using google apps script, and put in google sheets, command by using start/stop/reset button.

Comment: Can you please include some more details in your question, like what you've already tried and what error messages you might be getting? The more detailed and clear you can be, the more likely someone will be able to answer your question.

Comment: actually i have not done script writing, i just is the beginning user of google sheets. I mean I want to create something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbJeGG_Xv8M&t. in the video using excel VBA. please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

## A Javascript Timer for Gathering data off of a Spreadsheet

I built this as a test setup for one of my projects.  Here's the datatimer.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      #my_block{border:2px solid black;background-color:rgba(0,150,255,0.2);padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;}
      #conv_block{border: 1px solid black;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;}
      .bttn_block{padding:5px 5px 0px 0px;}
      .sndr_block {border:1px solid rgba(0,150,0,0.5);background-color:rgba(150,150,0,0.2);margin-bottom:2px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
    <div id="my_block" class="block form-group">
      <div class="sndr_block">
        <div id="myClock"></div>
        <br />Timer Duration(minutes):
        <br /><input id="txt1" type="text" size="4" class="action"/>
        <select id="sel1" onChange="loadTxt('sel1','txt1');">
          <option value="90000">1.5</option>
          <option value="96000">1.6</option>
          <option value="102000">1.7</option>
          <option value="108000">1.8</option>
          <option value="114000">1.9</option>
          <option value="120000" selected>2.0</option>
          <option value="126000">2.1</option>
          <option value="132000">2.2</option>
          <option value="138000">2.3</option>
          <option value="144000">2.4</option>
        </select>
        <div id="cntdiv"></div>
        <br /><strong>Timer Controls</strong>
        <div class="bttn_block"><input type="button" value="Start" name="startShow" id="startShow" onClick="startmytimer();" class="red" /></div>
        <div class="bttn_block"><input type="button" value="Stop" name="stopTimer" id="stopTimer" class="red" /></div>
        <div class="bttn_block"><input type="button" value="Single Ping" name="changedata" id="chgData" class="red" onClick="changeData();" /></div>

      </div>
      <div id="btn-bar">
        <br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" class="green" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
    <script>
    var idx=1;
    var myInterval='';
    var cnt=0;
      $(function() {
        $('#startTimer').click(startmytimer);
        $('#stopTimer').click(stopTimer);
        $('#txt1').val('120000');
        startTime();
      });

      function startTime(){
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        m = checkTime(m);
        s = checkTime(s);
        document.getElementById('myClock').innerHTML =
        h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
        var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
      }

      function checkTime(i){
        if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
        return i;
      }

      function startmytimer(){
        document.getElementById('cntdiv').innerHTML='<strong>Timer Started:</strong> ' + document.getElementById('myClock').innerHTML;
        myInterval=setInterval(changeData, Number($('#txt1').val()));
      }

      function stopTimer(){
        document.getElementById('cntdiv').innerHTML='Timer Stopped';
        clearInterval(myInterval);
      }

      function loadTxt(from,to){
        document.getElementById(to).value = document.getElementById(from).value;
      }

      function changeData(){
        $('#txt1').css('background','#ffffcc');
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(updateDisplay)
        .changeData();
      }

      function updateDisplay(t){
        $('#txt1').css('background','#ffffff');
        document.getElementById('cntdiv').innerHTML='<strong>Timer Running:</strong> Count= ' + ++cnt + ' <strong>Time:</strong> ' + t;
      }

     console.log('My Code');
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the datachanger.gs file:

```
function changeData(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sho=ss.getSheetByName('TradingTimes')
  var tmr=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss");
  var col2=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  var col3=new Date(col2).getTime();
  var col4=new Date(col2).getTime();
  var dA=[[col2,col3,col4]];
  sho.getRange('B2:D2').setValues(dA);
  return tmr;
}

function showTimerSideBar()
{
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('datatimer').setTitle('Javascript Trigger Generator');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

I was just watching the output from a sheet that had Google Finance cell functions in it.  But you can call anything you want as often as you like.

Here's what the dialog looks like:

[image]

Comment: thank you for any explanation. i have a little question. how do i display the countdown timer within the specified range in the active sheet.

Comment: You can put it on a sidebar or on a dialog (preferably modeless).

Comment: yes it's tried, but here I want to put it within a certain range in the sheet, not in the widget or dialog.. please help me. ;-)

Comment: To my knowledge that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can [attach actions to images](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets) in a google sheet. That way you can have a start, stop and reset buttons as images. When clicked the images can link to functions in the appscript which updates the time in single cell.

Below is the code, and here is a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14bcLPPvhTRsFCJ9DYgI7zlySg9eG8VwT2xaD916Lfhk/edit?usp=sharing) . See the "attach action to images" document on how to trigger the buttons if needed.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

function  countDownSeconds(seconds, minutes){
  while (minutes >=0){   
     sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(minutes);     
    while (seconds >= 0 ){     
      var m = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue()
      var s = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue()
      if (m === 'pausing' || s === 'pausing'|| m === 'reset' || s === 'reset' ) {
       return
      }      
      sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(seconds); 
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(1000)
      seconds --
    }    
    seconds = 59;
    minutes = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue();
    minutes --
  }
}

function startTimer(){
   var minutes = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue()
   var seconds = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue()
   countDownSeconds(seconds, minutes)

}

function pause(){
   var minutes = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue()
   var seconds = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue()
   sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue('pausing');  
   sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue('pausing');   
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   Utilities.sleep(1000);
   sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(minutes)
   sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(seconds)
}

function reset(){
   sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue('reset');  
   sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue('reset');   
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   Utilities.sleep(1000);
   sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(0)
   sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(0)
}
```

Comment: thank you for the advice given. btw, I may share with me about it.

Comment: I am very grateful for the assistance have given, but I have a question. how to put between minutes and second into one cell. ;-)

Comment: Hey @Jason Allshorn, I came here with the same question and managed to get code working from your answer, so thank you! I have only one concern - on my computer at least, both your code and my code seem to execute the timer at a rate slower than 1 second. Do you have any idea how it might be optimised?