# Why is a second taking longer than a second?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timer

I'm trying to create a timer in Google Apps Script, such that when there is a number displayed on a cell, and I start the script, the script will automatically decrement that number once every second, until the value reaches zero.

So I found [this answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47766484/1907765), and managed to implement code that does the same thing just fine. My one problem is that the code seems to run slowly - so that a second doesn't actually take a second. At a guess, it's between 1.5 to 2 seconds. This obviously isn't hugely ideal for a timer, and I'm wondering if it's a fixable problem. Is there a code optimization that might make my timer run on time, or something I've not factored in?

[Here's a link to a test spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kMNp7Wa1s9UxZnKZCsHfZA6dAoiICiIf5kJQA_u7Z-o/edit?usp=sharing), with the code in the Script Editor (it's View Only for safety, but the spreadsheet can be copied.) A UI control should initiate the "Start Timer" function if you want to test it.

Here's the full code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function onOpen() {
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 ui.createMenu("Timer controls")
 .addItem("Start Timer", "startTimer")
 .addToUi();
}

function startTimer() {
  var timer = ss.getRangeByName("Timer");
  var timeval = timer.getValue();
  while (timeval > 0) {
    timeval--;
    timer.setValue(timeval);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Every action in a script takes time so obviously your script is going to take longer than one second. I think a better way to time a script is to look at the execution logs or measure time at the beginning and at the end and subtract the values and divide by 1000 to get seconds

Comment: Thanks for the input Cooper - sadly, this wasn't obvious to me as I'm relatively new to Apps Script. Would you mind helping me out with how I could implement either method?

Comment: In perfect world your last line will take one second so what’s not to understand that the entire script will be more than one second?

Comment: Because my primary coding experience has been VB.NET, where most trivial functions will take an amount of time that I don't register - thus `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` does take one second for all intents and purposes.

Comment: I'm aware that Apps Script is a different ballgame, but not familiar with how to do either of the methods you propose, nor of any way to optimise my script to run faster - which is why I'm here. Do you have any insight into how I might be able to implement this? :)

Comment: Use new Date().getTime() at beginning and end and subtract to get milliseconds

Comment: @Cooper I think that [your old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47762352/1595451)  is what the OP needs.

Answer (score 2):

**Timer**

```
function undertest() {
  var start=new Date().getTime();//milliseconds
  //all your other code here
  Logger.log(Number((new Date().getTime()-start)/1000).toFixed(2));//seconds

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tl;Dr There is no fix for your code.

You are missing that there are communications processes between your web browser and Google servers...

and that Google Apps Script methods are slow,

and that editing a cell value triggers the recalculation of the whole spreadsheet.

You should start over and instead of using sever side code and Google Sheets to display a timer, follow the recommendation of Cooper on his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47762352/1595451) to the same question of the answer that in linked in the question: Use client-side code.