# Why does my Google App script auto refresh code not work?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I wrote a simple code to automatically refresh the digits in the Google sheet. I print the `i` with app script to the relevant place. Data needs to be refreshed every 15 seconds. But it doesn't work right. It should write `0` at the 15th second, `1` at the 30th, `2` at the 45th. But `0` doesn't write `1`, it just writes the `2` in the last loop. Why doesn't it write data every 15 seconds?

```
function exampleFunction() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var spreadSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("sheetname");
  var i = 0;

  while(true){
    activeSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(i);
    i++;
    Utilities.sleep(15000);
    
    if(i == 3){
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think that in this case, `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` is required to be used. Because the cell value is modified by `setValue` while the script is running. So, for example, how about putting `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after the line of `activeSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(i);`? [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47766484)

Comment: What you said worked. Problem solved, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For documentation reasons, I can confirm Tanaike's comment, it works with `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` as it is expected:

```
function exampleFunction() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var spreadSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("sheetname");
  var i = 0;

  while(true){
    activeSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(i);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush()
    i++;
    Utilities.sleep(15000);
    
    if(i == 3){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```