# Increment Cell value per second in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Say in cell `A1` I wrote value `0`. How can I increment the value of `A1` by 1 every second?

Comment: Unfortunately the minimum time duration for a time driven trigger is 1 minute.

Comment: You could do it from something like a sidebar using setTimout or setInterval and google.script.run.  The sidebar would have to remain active all of the time.

Comment: @Cooper do you mind to elaborate?  As TheWized mentioned above, I could not find less than 1 minute period triggering method?

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval They have examples

Comment: @Cooper so this is a Firefox browser script or something...?

Comment: It a javascript reference.  The side bar is html and you can use setInterval to call functions periodically and in those function you can call google.script.run and run server side function from them.  Once a second is fairly fast to complete function on the server side.

Comment: Here's a link to a timer that I've written in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47762352/7215091

Comment: this won't do when done on a daily basis when using normal time driven trigger. for sure you'd reach some quota

Comment: @Cooper what you mean by saying side bar? Where do I write JS code?

Comment: In SpreadsheetApp.getUi() there are several different dialog methods available in that class and one is called sidebar and it displays on the right hand side of the screen next to the spreadsheet.  But in any case I'm just suggesting that you can use the clientside Javascript to three server side functions with google.script.run.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a script on a recurring interval you can use triggers; however, as @TheWizEd mentioned, [time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#:%7E:text=A%20time%2Ddriven%20trigger%20(also,once%20per%20hour%20at%20most.)) only let you run scripts at 1 minute intervals as minimum.